# Analyse and simplify technical text (about software engineering)

Tags: language, word-processor, spell-checker, writing, grammar

I know there are Grammarly, LanguageTool, Hemingway editor and more choices to analyze my text for correctness and readability. But is there a more specialized program specifically for a technical text that would benefit from suggestions how it can be written so that it becomes easier to understand? Shorter sentences are usually better, and for that I found that the Hemingway Editor is better than Grammarly and the others. But isn't there some specialized software that only analyses technical text in English for readability and simplicity, and then the spellchecker and correctness can be something else e.g. Grammarly?

Update: I found a service named Wordtune that is even closer to what I'd like to use. Less about correct spelling or grammar and more about the wording. A spellchecker and grammar checker can be used as complement to the rewording function.

Comment: What OS shall that program run on, and how much you'd be willing to spend if it came to paid solutions?

Comment: Any OS or even an API that takes plain text will do. I have a budget compared to what the other solutions take (Grammarly, Hemingway Editor etc.) but Grammarly and LanguageTool don't really solve the problem, and Hemingway Editor, while being closer to a solution, is rather primitive in its analysis: Adding one word to a sentence changed its verdict from "good" to "too complicated", in this case it was the difference between "...security of a system..." and "...security of a computer system..." that made a difference between OK and "too hard" in Hemingway, which I consider being false positive

Comment: OpenAI has a ["Summarize for a 2nd Grader"](https://beta.openai.com/examples/default-pummarize) API but it costs money, and it probably cannot summarize *highly specialized* technical stuff correctly. However you can adjust the text compactness, with parameters. OpenAI also has a [TL;DR](https://beta.openai.com/examples/default-tldr-summary) service.